# Clear cache Elasticsearch not clearing much data

Tags: caching, elasticsearch

When running `curl -XPOST node1:9200/_cache/clear`

I expected a large amount of cache to disappear in each node.

But when looking at bigdesk, cache size doesn't seem to drop a lot.
[image: One node cache graph]

Shouldn't it drop a lot??

The main problem from that is that each node has generally very high cache size and it's the reason for exceptions like below:

`ElasticsearchException[org.elasticsearch.common.breaker.CircuitBreakingException: Data too large, data for field [ts] would be larger than limit of [24108466176/22.4gb]]`

Another thing is I don't see any cache eviction generally(not after clear_cache only), there are no properties for cache eviction set in settings(perhaps some should be set?). The only property set is `fielddata.breaker.limit: 75%`

What can be done for handling better cache in elasticseach?

ElasticSearch version: 1.3.5

Comment: What ES version is this?

Comment: Added version on question(1.3.5)

Comment: Moved to 1.3.7 . All issues are resolved